# Install Eclipse Less plugin, Resource was edited concurrently

Tags: eclipse, plugins, less

I just installed Eclipse plugin for LESS (http://www.normalesup.org/~simonet/soft/ow/eclipse-less.fr.html).

I followed the install instructions there. Now I am able to open an LESS file with the LESS editor coming with the plugin.

but when I coding , the eclipse tell me that :

```
Resource was edited concurrently
The resource is currently edited in another editor,Do you want to continue?
```

who can tell me why? the version of eclipse is 4.4 Luna, and the less plugin version is 1.0.19

Comment: Same situation here. I've opened a new issue on github, let's see how far we can go with it: https://github.com/vtst/ow/issues/241

Comment: Maybe this is related to Eclipse Luna ? This plugin worked well on Kepler.